# Tableau Peformance- Custom SQL Queries

Tags: sql-server, performance, tableau-api

I am essentially building gone report that ingests two types of data. One is the receptionists data. Which is each receptionists stats by day. But then the data gets a little more granular and is each call for each receptionist.

Essentially the report does two things gives receptionist performance then a person can click and prompt the same dashboard sheet to update with specific call log etc.

So basically this data set is huge and held as an export so it will be faster an I limit the data to this month and last month (minimum requirement). I have also eliminated any unnecessary columns.

I am curious if I should create two separate custom queries in Tableau then create referential field or should I bring both custom queries inside of one workbook and join them together. At first I had the two connections separate but now I brought them together and am noticing some performance issues. What are some of my options?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have two seperate queries since for the first view doesnt need all the additional details you want to show in the drill down. 
Use an action filter and link the two sheets(which use different data sources) by selecting the specific fields when configuring the action filter.
Performance wise this is a good approach.